# How to search exact number using regexp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I found a jsfiddle code that can search multiple words and will result to multiple result.
Now i want to search on the numbers column only. I tried searching 2 and the result is two column which is 2 and 24.  i know why because 2 has also in 24. i want only the 2 will be displayed. but the function of the jsfiddle of "multiple" search will not be affected. like if i search "2 24" or "2|24" that's the time it will display 2 and 24

here's the table

```
    <input id="emp_search" />
<input id="search" type="button" value="search" />
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>number</th>
       <th>letters</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Lennon</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>sf</td>
       <td>Male</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Paul</td>
       <td>McCartney</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>tj</td>
       <td>Male</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>George</td>
       <td>Harrison</td>
       <td>24</td>
       <td>ge</td>
       <td>Female</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Ringo</td>
       <td>Starr</td>
       <td>36</td>
       <td>hg</td>
       <td>Female</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and js

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
RegExp.escape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
};
}
jQuery(function ($) {
///search this table
$(' #search ').click(function () {
    var searchthis = new RegExp(' '+$(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/ /g,"|"), 'i');
    $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
      //  var text = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase().trim();
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        $(this).toggle(searchthis.test(text));
    });
});
});
```

and here's the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ANLgD/30/

Comment: If you want to search against an exact value instead of looking for text that includes that value why not just use `===` instead of a regex?

Comment: @scott.korin then what if i searched "2 24" what will happen?

Comment: You'd have to parse your search text and split it on space or | and search for each value.

Comment: @scott.korin  uhm... would you mind posting your answer. sorry sir. i not really good in programmin.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for regex here

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $input = $(' #emp_search ');
    ///search this table
    $(' #search ').click(function () {
        var s = $.map($.trim($input.val()).split(/\s+/), function(val){
            return '\\b' + RegExp.escape(val) + '\\b'
        }).join('|');
        var searchthis = new RegExp(s, 'i');
        $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
            var text = $.trim($(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text());
            $(this).toggle(searchthis.test(text));
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JcWJP/)

Comment: Yes sir. as i have said on my post i dont want to i affect the functionality of searching multiple instead what if i want to search an exact number . example "2" or "3". that will be only 1 row. containing that "2"  or "3". now if "2 24" that's the only time it will display 2 rows containg 2 and 24. or "3 36" .

Comment: sir. can i ask more help. where should i put the find('td:nth-child(3))' because i will search on a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var re = /[^0-9]/g;
var error = re.test(BlkAccountIdV);

error will be true if value of BlkAccountIdV is not numeric
```